# Can I store hashed passwords?

Tags: api, authentication, hash, cryptography

The flickr authentication API is described here:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.spec.html

I have implemented something very similar for an xml-rpc based protocol, to allow signing requests without using SSL.

It basically works as follow:

For a remote function call

```
doSomething(foo='hello', bar='world')
```

I first sort argument by name, giving:

```
('bar', 'world'), ('foo', 'hello')
```

then I do string concatenation:

```
 m = "bar:world;foo:hello"
```

then I append the secret key:

```
 m = "bar:world;foo:hello;someSecret"
```

and finally the signature is a md5 hash of message m.

The same process is made on the server to check if the one who called the function actually knew the secret key.

For now passwords are stored in plain text on the server side. Is there a way to store hashed passwords instead ?

My guess is that the md5 hash function lacks additivity for this to be possible, but maybe it can still be achieved by some clever construction ?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you ask about your client to flickr api or about your client-server pair? There are some authentications which allow you not to store a plain-text password on the server or which will not send a plaintext password while authenticating, e.g. SRP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_Protocol

Comment: for basic signing you can use HMAC. If you want not to store a cleartext password on server, you can store md5() (or stronger hash, e.g. PBKDF) of it and use md5(password) both at client and at server to sign and to check sign.

Comment: Well, my first concern is to avoid sending the password (no SSL) and without requiring to store this password unencrypted on the server. If possible using the same protocol but I can change it if there is a better one. 

The bonus question is: can flickr do that given their current authentication protocol ?

Comment: Flickr uses weak signing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC#Design_principles - here is some discussion about `MD5(SECRET + DATA)` and `MD5(DATA + SECRET)`. HMAC is stronger.

Comment: @osgx Doing that is pointless - md5(password) is now your actual password, and the attacker doesn't need the original password.

Comment: @ascobol Why don't you want to use SSL?

Comment: @Nick Johnson, using md5(password) will made a password storage on server a bit more secure. If the server will be hacked and user reuse the password anywhere.... but plain md5() is not so strong. So it can be better to use PBKDF to store password on server or even switch to the secure password storing and checking scheme.

Comment: @osgx Sure, this minimally helps to protect the _user_ from password reuse. That's not the question, though - the question is, can he avoid storing the password in plaintext so a compromise of the password database is sufficient to authenticate as that user, and hashing the password does not help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: practically speaking, no.

Long answer: Hashing the password on either end doesn't help, as the hash of the password can now be used by the attacker to authenticate. See [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication#Password_storage) in the wikipedia article on Challenge-Response authentication for more details.

There *are* algorithms that allow you to verify the user's password without them providing it to you or you storing it, known as a [Zero Knowledge Password Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_password_proof). One example is the [Secure Remote Password Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_remote_password_protocol). Such protocols tend to be complex, however, and implementing one yourself is complicated and probably unwise.

An easier solution is to use public key cryptography, and issue your users private keys to which you know the public part. They can then sign their messages to authenticate and identify themselves. SSL/TLS provide ready-made implementations of this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest moving off of MD5 to a stronger hash function, such as the SHA2 family.

That said, nothing prevents you from using the same construction you have above, where "someSecret" is actually a hash of the password. This will cause you to do two hashing operations on the client and one on the server, while keeping the hashed password in storage.

I would also second using an actual HMAC instead of doing your own construction. Also, instead of hashing the password, use at least PBKDF2 with a reasonable amount of iterations. Therefore you will get your client to do HMAC(data, PBKDF2(someSecret, 1000)) and the server will just store PBKDF2(someSecret, 1000), then do HMAC(data, storedResult).

Comment: PBKDF2 .. 1000 is too small. It can be easily brute-forced on modern GPU. WPA2 uses 4096, and it is effecivelly brute-forced (up to 25k/second of WPA2 on single GTX 295; 30k/sec on top ATI http://golubev.com/gpuest.htm).

Comment: This is just an example to illustrate point, not actual recommendation to the number of rounds.

Comment: As I commented above, using the hashed password on both ends is completely pointless: The hash output is now, to all intents and purposes, your password. An attacker can steal the hash, and use that to authenticate.

Comment: While I agree with you that the hash is equivalent for attacking this particular service, you have to look at what the threat model is and what is intended to be protected here. If an attacker gets access to the account database, the actual service is probably compromised enough that the attacker doesn't need actual credentials. Storing a transform of the password prevents attackers from using the credentials against other sites if password is reused. I don't see how ZKP will help you in the face of attacker compromising the service : )